# Getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetTop' of null error for scroll

Tags: javascript

I am having an issue where I get a uncaught type error, but the script still works. I would like to resolve this but cannot seem to see the issue. Any help is greatly appreciated! Script is below.

```
StickyNav: function() {
    let mainNavLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".js-pdp-link");
    let mainSections = document.querySelectorAll("section");
    let lastId;
    let cur = [];

    window.addEventListener("scroll", event => {
        let fromTop = window.scrollY + 70;

        mainNavLinks.forEach(link => {
            let section = document.querySelector(link.hash);

        if (section.offsetTop <= fromTop && section.offsetTop + section.offsetHeight > fromTop) {
            link.classList.add("js-active");
       } else {
           link.classList.remove("js-active");
       }
       });
    });
}
```

Comment: The error means `section` is undefined. Debug to figure out why it is undefined

Comment: There's a value of `hash` that doesn't have an associated section.  Check the values to make sure they're what you expect, and double-check that you didn't make any typos or anything.

Comment: `document.querySelector` might return `null`. Any method in javascript that might return null should be checked to see if it is null or has a value before attempting to reference properties of it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector#Return_value

Comment: @JohnMontgomery you nailed it. I am missing a section that i am linking to with the sticky nav which causes the error, updated the section with the id and it worked perfectly. Sorry that it was a simple answer. Thanks everyone for all their suggestions!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do:

```
let mainNavLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".js-pdp-link");

mainNavLinks.forEach(link => {
  let section = document.querySelector(link.hash);
```

You are iterating all the elements with the `.js-pdp-link` class and, if they implement the [HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils) interface (*i.e.* is an `a` or an `area` element), extracting their [hash](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/hash) property. Then, you use the `hash` as a selector.

It can fail in three different ways:

1. If the target element doesn't implement `HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils`, `link.hash` returns `undefined`.
2. If the `href` attribute contains no hash, `link.hash` returns an empty string.
3. If there is no element with a `id` equal to that `hash`, `querySelector(link.hash)` is `null`.

The case 2 results in `SyntaxError: '' is not a valid selector` when you try `document.querySelector(link.hash)`.

The other two allow you to run the `querySelector` but result in `section` being `null`. Then, if you try to access its `.offsetTop` property, you will get `TypeError: section is null`.

Comment: Yup that was it, One of my sections was missing the corresponding id that I had for the sticky nav menu item. Thanks!!